# XML(SwipeView) Layout Attribute is returned as null

Tags: java, android, xml, reference, nul

I have a [SwipeView](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout/wiki/SwipeAdapter) item in my XML and when I try to access it from my java class, `sometimes it returns null`. At somepoint yesterday, while having a break point to debug everything was working fine but that was only for a couple of times. I already tried cleaning my project.

**Custom ListView XML Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <com.daimajia.swipe.SwipeLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeEvents" - this does not belong to activity_all_events
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    More Code...
    </com.daimajia.swipe.SwipeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Java Class** - this calls the XML layout that includes a ListView of CustomAdapter & custom xml view

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_events);

        SwipeLayout swipeLayout =  (SwipeLayout)findViewById(R.id.swipeEvents); - this does not belong to activity_all_events.xml
        //set show mode.
        swipeLayout.setShowMode(SwipeLayout.ShowMode.LayDown);

        More Code...
}
```

**Error Log**

```
                                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{cmario.com.xxxx/cmario.com.xxxx.events.AllEvents}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.daimajia.swipe.SwipeLayout.setShowMode(com.daimajia.swipe.SwipeLayout$ShowMode)' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.daimajia.swipe.SwipeLayout.setShowMode(com.daimajia.swipe.SwipeLayout$ShowMode)' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at cmario.com.xxxx.events.AllEvents.onCreate(AllEvents.java:94)
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
```

1. Anything to do with my constructor?
2. The point that I am trying to access the XML property(before the CustomAdapter is initialized)? Tried to that after the `CustomAdapter` is called but still the same output

Thanks in advance you anyone who is willing to help me with suggestions

Comment: `com.daimajia.swipe` is your package name ? Show error logcat

Comment: No, my package name is something else

Comment: `SwipeLayout` class calling from your package ?

Comment: can you be more descriptive?

Comment: Okay,i will.Can you post your `error log`

Comment: updated the question

Comment: show use package name of SwipeLayout class

Comment: https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout/issues/146

Comment: @DhawalSodhaParmar I think so .Problem for Package name

Comment: set `SwipeLayout` class  `packagename.SwipeLayout`

Comment: I don't how this comment will help me solve my question yet...